# How to attach short bottom plate for door frame to concrete floor?

Tags: basement, framing, door-frame

I'm framing out my basement, which I've done once before in an old house. I use the treated wood (green board?) for the bottom plate, raise up the frames, get everything level, and use cut nails to attach into the concrete.

But for framing out doors, where I want to have the door close to the beginning of the wall, I need to somehow put multiple nails through a 5 or 6 inch piece of green board, and I don't have any room with the king studs and jack studs, to do it after I build the frame, but I don't want to toenail, either, makes keeping it plumb difficult.

More importantly, when I tried this once already, I split the green board. Should I just attach the frame real well to the perpendicular wall and not worry about it? Should I liquid nails the bottom plate to the concrete? Both?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding.  Are you saying that you will end up with a bottom plate that is too short to accept nails without splitting, and you want to avoid this?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The bottom plate on the first doorway I framed had too little space between the king stud and the end of the frame for me to hammer the concrete nail. So I tried doing it piece-meal, so I could cover the concrete nail after I fastened it to the concrete, but then I split the bottom plate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your PT plates across the doorway to begin with, then cut them out after the fact. (Predrill the plate and use tapcon style screws and you won't split even a short bit of plate.) The upside of this is that you'll have a straight line across the doorway. Build a wall on this with another bottom plate/studs/top plate and it's easy to plumb it.

Alternately, you could skip the plate and attach the framing to the wall, but that could have issues with the lumber running nice and straight in line with your opening. Best practices would have you use pressure treated lumber in contact with concrete. (It's a bit of a waste of lumber to have 4 or 5-2x4s stacked up where you don't need them. Plus you'll have a hard time putting a light switch there.)

Comment: This is great! It had never occurred to me to use tapcons. That will surely solve this. I will definitely run the plate across the whole doorway, it just doesn't solve the problem of how to fit two fasteners in a very short run. The tapcons should, certainly. Thanks again!